# How to find the password of mysql on desktop docker in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

After Laravel installation by sail and docker on windows, I run the server by:

```
./vendaor/bin/sail up -d
```

and this is the containers:

[image]

I can't connect to MySQL by `user: root and password` and `port 3306`

```
docker exec -it app-mysql-1 mysql -u root -p
```

I delete the app-mysql-1 from app containers and `Run` a MySQL image but problem still exists and I can't connect to MySQL and make or migrate.

I can find the auto generated MySQL password and can change it but can't connect and use this one in `app containers`

[image]

How I can connect to MySQL in the `app containers`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't change the default Sail database user then you should use:

User: sail 
Password: password

And in `./.env`:

```
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Worked! thankyou, I can connect but can't migrate by ./vendor/bin/sail PHP artisan migrate, get the error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE').
I made a bb named app
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
but get error !

Comment: Default MySQL username and password, Laravel Sail. I couldn't find the real answer to this question ANYWHERE, just workarounds.  WTH. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose.yml find these lines:

```
mariadb:
    image: 'mariadb:10'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

You can see the root password.